# How can I post new comment with Graph API into Social Comments Box?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have facebook social comments box. How can I post comment through graph API to it?

Comment: are you able to get correct answer because i also face same problem right now please check below link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762239/upload-comments-to-particular-post-of-facebook-with-object-id-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762239/upload-comments-to-particular-post-of-facebook-with-object-id-android)

Answer (score 7):

I can give you half the answer to this question, but still need the other half very much myself. You can post a reply to an existing comment within Social Comments box by finding its **post_fbid**. To get this you can use FQL such as:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT post_fbid, id FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url ='[ PAGE_URL ]')&access_token=[ ACCESS_TOKEN ]
```

This query will need to be run through an escape() with the PAGE_URL and then used for an HTTP GET request:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20post_fbid%2C%20id%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FROM%20comment%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20object_id%20IN%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(SELECT%20comments_fbid%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FROM%20link_stat%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20url%20%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com')&access_token=[ ACCESS_TOKEN ]
```

With the **post_fbid** you can make a reply by doing an HTTP POST to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[ POST_FBID ]/comments/?access_token=[ ACCESS_TOKEN ]&message=[ MESSAGE]
```

Now for posting a new comment to the page [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796930/programmatically-posting-facebook-comments) used to work until recently with an HTTP POST:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=[ PAGE_URL ]&access_token=[ ACCESS_TOKEN ]&message=[ MESSAGE]
```

But currently this is consistently returning:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

I hope this helps a bit and if anyone can shed some light if posting a new comment like this is even possible anymore it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Guess I am not the only one experiencing the OAuthException then :-/ Let me know if you find a solution for that one...

Comment: Yes, guys, I tested it this September - it worked. Now it does not. Usual thing :-)

Comment: you need to set `&method=POST` when you want to post something

Comment: it seems you are posting with user access_token not with page access_token

Comment: More than one year later, the bug still exists. This is a shame

Answer (score 2):

Seems that it is not possible, and will never be:

> This functionality was never and is not intended to be available.
>
> An error message has been added for this case: "Comments may not be
>   added to a comment plugin"

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164794086987157

Answer (score -2):

**Its very easy** as you post on user feed after getting access_token with publish stream token

I assume you use PHP SDK if you need in other let me known

You just need **Step 4** but i give you more details in **Step 1 to 3** so you can understand and do clearly

**Step 1**

get the user access token

```
        $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        echo "</br>" . 'Access_Token:' . $token;
```

**Step 2**
set default access token and profile

```
        $facebook->setAccessToken($token);
```

**Step 3**
compile the post

```
    $WallPost = array(
    'message' => 'hey this app is cool!!',
    'link' => $canvas_page,
    'caption' => 'caption',
    'description' => 'Test Description',
            );  // you can also use 'picture', 'description', 'source'....
```

**Step 4**
post to wall or your **Social Comment Plugin**

```
        $response = $facebook->api('/me' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost);
```

Thanks

Comment: This is for pushing on the timeline, not a comment, you need to edit step 4

Comment: The question was clearly asking how to post a comment to a comments social plugin, and not how to post to a user feed/wall...