# POST comment to a URL

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I post new comment with Graph API into Social Comments Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827480/how-can-i-post-new-comment-with-graph-api-into-social-comments-box)

I'm trying to POST a comment to a page URL in order to reproduce the comment widget functionality using the graph API.  While I can get the post_fbid of an existing comment and post a response to it, I cannot post to the page itself.  I've tried using the `comments_fbid` (`link_stat` table) and the object `id` (`object_url` table) and both return `An unknown error has occurred.` error messages.

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827480/how-can-i-post-new-comment-with-graph-api-into-social-comments-box/7896452#7896452) and [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7634674/post-a-comment-against-a-url), but I'd like do know definitively if it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible currently.  Here's the FB bug tracking the issue:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164794086987157