# How to add comment in website page by API?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments, facebook-rest-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I post new comment with Graph API into Social Comments Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827480/how-can-i-post-new-comment-with-graph-api-into-social-comments-box)

I try to comment a web page by API directly with this URL.

In this web page, I have got a social plugin for comments (for this part, it's Okay), and I would like to send comment from an iOS App with native components. I search a way to publish comments in this web page by request, but I don't find it in Facebook developers.

I have all permissions: publish_stream and publish_action

I tried:

1) Graph API :

- URL: https://graph.facebook.com//comments
- POST: message = test

=> return false

2) Legacy REST API :

- URL: https://api.facebook.com/method/comments.add
- POST : access_token, object_id (= ), text and title

=> Error code 100 or 200

I have all permissions to publish and I don't understand why my request failed!

Thank you for your help