# Facebook Social Plugin in to post comment in android

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Facebook social plugin in my native android app.

Till now i have done these steps.

- get app id by creating app i Facebook developer console.
- get code from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/
- After getting code just for testing purpose i make a webpage and load this webpage in      web-view in android.
- all comments are showing in the web-view.
- But there is a button that    says login before post a comment.. I
  have access token because my app    requires SSO using Facebook sdk.

So is there any way so that i can use the access token to post comment in the Facebook social plugin (that is loaded in web-view) that is generated during login from Facebook

I am using that java-script code in webpage that is loaded in web-view.

```
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script><script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'MY_APP_ID',  
      status     : true,  
      xfbml      : true    
    });
  };
  (function(){
     if (document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk')) {return;}
     var firstScriptElement = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     var facebookJS = document.createElement('script'); 
     facebookJS.id = 'facebook-jssdk';
     facebookJS.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     firstScriptElement.parentNode.insertBefore(facebookJS, firstScriptElement);
   }());
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div  class="fb-comments" data-href="MY_URL" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: In short, not possible, facebook does not allow it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827480/how-can-i-post-new-comment-with-graph-api-into-social-comments-box