# how to post a comment base on an url using php facebook api?

Tags: php, facebook

how to post a comment base on an url using php facebook api?

for example , my page url is :
http://www.persunmall.com/p12345

I want to use facebook php api to post an comment for the page, I know that I can use

```
$res = $facebook->api('/100005658545226_193443144187636(post_id)/comments', 'POST', $req);
```

to post an comment , but my page url had never posted to facebook, then it has no post_id at all. 
then how can i do ?

Comment: Post comment on a page required publish_stream permissions.Check if you have provided that permission.

Comment: I have perminssion, I want to post coment for a url , no need post_id , how to do

Comment: You may check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827480/how-can-i-post-new-comment-with-graph-api-into-social-comments-box