# Upload comments to particular post of facebook with object_id android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-comments

Hello friends I want to post comment to particular post in facebook with my android app, below is my code-

**I Fetch All comments from  URL which is below**

**http://retirementhomeslisting.com/home-detail/canterbury-place-83**

```
Bundle mBundle=new Bundle();
mBundle.putString("message","testing...1234555"); 
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Facebook fb=new Facebook(getResources().getString(R.string.fb_app_id));
try {
    fb.request("478409145610921/comments",mBundle,"POST");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here I provide one link which you can see all comment list with respective above `object_id`

[Link for comment list for 478409145610921 object_id](http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=JSON&query=select%20post_fbid,%20fromid,%20object_id,%20text,%20time%20from%20comment%20where%20object_id%20in%20%28select%20comments_fbid%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20=%22http://retirementhomeslisting.com/home-detail/canterbury-place-83%22%29)

When i run above code comment is not post with respective object_id so Any idea how can i solve it?
**EDIT Answer**

```
Bundle mBundle=new Bundle();
                        mBundle.putString("message","testing...1234555"); 
                        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                        Facebook fb=new Facebook(getResources().getString(R.string.fb_app_id));
                        try {
                        fb.request("1309634065_478409145610921/comments",mBundle,"POST");

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To post a comment on a post, you need a `post_id` instead of `object_id`.

So your API call must be-

```
/{post_id}/comments
```

(`post_id` is also a field in the [comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) table)

**Edit:**

You must be using a comment plugin and trying to post a comment to that. Unfortunately, facebook don't allows you to do that! (Logical- since most of them are public, to avoid spamming, else anyone could flood comments to that post)

If you check the response here, you'll get:

```
{
  "error": {
     "message": "(#100) Comments may not be added to a comment plugin", 
     "type": "OAuthException", 
     "code": 100
  }
}
```

You can test these API call on [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=478409145610921/comments) also.

Comment: Sahil Mittal : post_id in my case post_fbid which i get above json formate is it you say?

Comment: No, change your query. [Check this link](http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=JSON&query=select%20post_fbid,post_id,%20fromid,%20object_id,%20text,%20time%20from%20comment%20where%20object_id%20in%20%28select%20comments_fbid%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20=%22http://retirementhomeslisting.com/home-detail/canterbury-place-83%22%29). Your postid is `1309634065_478409145610921`

Comment: Sahil Mittal :I try your code but still not post comment in the post!! see my edit code pls.

Comment: But what's the response this time?

Comment: Sahil Mottal :: When i post comment just print link like
04-01 09:39:47.105: D/Facebook-Util(6675): POST URL: https://graph.facebook.com/1309634065_758983910781864/comments

Comment: Sahil Mittal :: no when i paste this url to browser it give message "Sorry, this page isn't available"

Comment: My bad. You are fetching the comments from a url! You didn't mention that in a question! I'll check

Comment: Sahil Mittal : ohh  ya brother !! i forgot it for mention i fetch all comments from url !! now see my edit line in above

Comment: Sahil Mittal  : So using url it is not possible right?

Comment: No. Someone posted it as a bug earlier: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164794086987157. But it was closed saying: `This functionality was never and is not intended to be available.` So, this is not possible! Only the comments on the facebook are accessible via graph api. You can only fetch the comments from url.

Comment: Sahil Mittal  Ok bro.. Thnaks for your time and effort !! but thenafter i will accept your answer and +1 vote for that

Comment: Great! :) If you find some issue using the facebook APIs you may contact me in case your question not getting attention here

Answer (score 0):

Using Graph API:

```
...
if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
      initWithGraphPath:@"post_id/likes"
      parameters: @{ @"like" : @"true"}
      HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
      startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"It was liked.");
         }
     }];
}
...
```