# Is it possible to use the graph API to create a comment for a given URL without an existing object ID?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments

The documentation only mentions that you can pull comments made on a URL 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

I saw this Q on SO: [Programmatically posting Facebook comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796930/programmatically-posting-facebook-comments) <-- however in the graph API explorer it will not allow me to make a POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=mywebsite.com/thingID

So is it possible to create comments for a URL that does not have an existing object ID?

Thanks!