# Facebook Social Plugin - How do I retrieve comments embedded in a site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

**Problem**

I have a unique question that might have not been answered before.

I want to post an image to a Facebook social plugin which I have tried getting a listing of posts from two separate URLs.

**First step I have tried to get this to work**

I am currently trying to get a list of posts by the desired URL (**Unsuccessful URL 2**).

I found the following question on StackOverflow and tried adding the URL into the address bar for both websites below.

[Programmatically posting Facebook comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796930/programmatically-posting-facebook-comments)

URL 1 works fine, but URL 2 does not.

**1) Successful URL** *Correct JSON Returned*

http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://techcrunch.com/2011/07/22/big-surprise-the-ipad-trumps-android-tablets-at-the-office/

**2) Unsuccessful URL** *Empty JSON Returned*

http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=https://www.change.org/p/set-armeniangenocidedoodle-on-april-24-googledoodles/u/10495296?utm_source=petition_update&utm_medium=facebook&utm_campaign=fb_comment

**Empty JSON Response**

```
{
   "https://www.change.org/p/set-armeniangenocidedoodle-on-april-24-googledoodles/u/10495296?utm_source=petition_update": {
      "comments": {
         "data": [

         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**Question**

*Why can I not get any JSON data for URL 2 ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can I not get any JSON data for URL 2 ?

Because you passed the *wrong* URL, by failing to properly URL-encode the parameter value.

`http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=https://www.change.org/p/set-armeniangenocidedoodle-on-april-24-googledoodles/u/10495296?utm_source=petition_update&utm_medium=facebook&utm_campaign=fb_comment`

Let’s take that apart, shall we?

You pass one parameter `ids` with the value `https://www.change.org/p/set-armeniangenocidedoodle-on-april-24-googledoodles/u/10495296?utm_source=petition_update`, and then two more parameters `utm_medium` with value `facebook` and `utm_campaign` with value `fb_comment`.

**The ampersand separates URL parameters.** If you don’t want it to do that, but have it be part of a *parameter value* instead – then you need to URL-encode it properly.

http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.change.org%2Fp%2Fset-armeniangenocidedoodle-on-april-24-googledoodles%2Fu%2F10495296%3Futm_source%3Dpetition_update%26utm_medium%3Dfacebook%26utm_campaign%3Dfb_comment

(Not only the ampersand was encoded here, but the whole parameter value. You should do that whenever you put any value into a URL context.)

Comment: Thank you so much CBroe!!   So a follow up question, when ever I have a sub url such as the one provided in my example, do I need to only URL encode when I have the ampersand separator in the sub url?

Comment: As I said, you should always encode any value you put into a URL context.